# Make seaborn factorplot black and white

Tags: python, seaborn

Given a seaborn factorplot like here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X_Axis':[1,3,5,7,10,20],
                   'col_2':[.4,.5,.4,.5,.5,.4],
                   'col_3':[.7,.8,.9,.4,.2,.3],
                   'col_4':[.1,.3,.5,.7,.1,.0],
                   'col_5':[.5,.3,.6,.9,.2,.4]})

df = df.melt('X_Axis', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
g = sns.factorplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=df)
```

I am trying to make the plot black and white. A certain graph should be black (say col2) while the rest should be gray.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the palette attribute:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=df,  palette=['black', 'grey', 'grey', 'grey'])
```